# how to pass parameter in java class like kotlin

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, kotlin

I'm trying to implement unit test in old java project but trying to learn it from Kotlin course cause most of android tutorials now are in Kotlin, the course use Kotlin class this way how I do the same with java

```
@Module
open class ApiModule {
 @Provides
  fun provideApi(): Api {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
      .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
      .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
      .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
      .build()
      .create(Api::class.java)
  }
@Provides
  open fun provideApiService(): ApiService {
     return ApiService()
  }
}
```

the questions is how to generate the next class ApiModuleTest in java?

```
class ApiModuleTest(val mockService: ApiService): ApiModule() {
   override fun provideApiService(): ApiService {
      return mockService
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like you need to learn some Kotlin first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This definition

```
class ApiModuleTest(val mockService: ApiService): ApiModule() {
    override fun provideApiService(): ApiService {
        return mockService
    }
}
```

tranlates roughly as

```
class ApiModuleTest extends ApiModule {
    final ApiService mockService;

    ApiModuleTest(ApiService mockService) {
        this.mockService = mockService);
    }

    @Override
    public ApiService provideApiService() {
        return mockService;
    }
}
```

For references see:

- https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html
- https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inheritance.html